# iOS In App Purchase buy several products

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am trying to test in app purchase for non-consumable. It works fine. I have 10 products. I want to select several products and buy in one transaction. I tried array with SKPayment method. It doesn't work. How do I buy multiple product one click?

Single product work fine;

```
func paymentQueueWithProduct(product : SKProduct){

    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self);

    let payment = SKPayment(product: product);
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);

}
```

I need to buy several product one transaction. For example;

```
func paymentQueueWithProduct(products : [SKProduct]){

    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self);

    let payment = SKPayment(product: products);
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);

}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Provide relevant details and code in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot purchase multiple products in a single transaction unless they are multiple of the same product (you can set a quantity of up to 10).

Perhaps consider adding IAPs that combine the benefits of groups of your existing IAPs (for example if you sell "level 1" "level 2" "level 3" consider selling "level 1-3" as well.

Unrelated, but you might want to observe the payment queue only once, rather than trying to add yourself as an observer each time a purchase is attempted.

Payment is described here and only discussed buying one product at a time:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/RequestPayment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW2

Comment: Hello, I would like to implement like you say here "level 1", "level 2", "level 3", as well as "level1-3". The problem is that when buying a group, there should be a way to mark also the individual items as purchased, or the system will have problems on multiple machines. How can I solve this ? what to do is an user on a second machine with the same Apple ID tries to purchase an item that is part of a group ? how to determine it is already purchased ? thanks

Comment: @AlfonsoTesauro Just also check if they've purchased the group with whatever check you are doing to see if they've purchased the individual item.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben, now I have the problem, like you say, of checking if the items have been purchased. I am trying to use this code: self.request = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] init];
self.request.delegate = self;  [self.request start]; but it needs user interaction and asks the password to the user. I am lost

Comment: for single items, the store will always respond with a failure for a product that is already purchased. A product will never be purchased twice. In the lack of a real-time mechanism, this cannot be guaranteed for groups and their individual products. Am I missing something ?

Comment: The receipt request is a separate issue. If you install from Xcode you won't have a receipt so you need to call refresh, but live you will always have a receipt (and seldom need to ask for it to be refreshed). All of your purchases will be in the receipt. If you want to see if (A), (B), or (C) was purchased, check if (ABC) was purchased first, then check the individual ones. It'll be up to you not to allow double purchase based on that info.

Comment: My problem is that, unless I refresh it manually (which requires user interaction), the receipt is not guaranteed to be updated with the latest purchases. I would like to avoid refreshing it manually.

Comment: Your receipt should always have your latest purchases. That is how receipt verification is possible.

Comment: In my tests, at least in the sandbox environment, the receipt is not live updated. I have asked the apple developer support with a ticket and they have answered that selling groups of items is not supported. I don't know what to think. Thanks

Comment: Is your problem that your receipt isn't update on install from Xcode? That's a limitation of sandbox testing. Live apps will have a receipt and when they install and it will have up to date purchases. When you make a purchase in any environment of non-consumables, your receipt will contain those items. You probably want to set a macro on your test builds that forces the receipt refresh on install. You can't buy multiple different IAPs at once, but you can buy something that represents multiple things in your app AFAIK.

Comment: To simplify the example, let's assume we have an application installed on two Macs. On both Macs, the app has received a receipt upon installation, so this is not an issue. What I am saying is that that receipt only contains IAP items up to the point in time in which it was installed, receiving the receipt. Subsequent purchases will not update the receipt automatically. If you want to refresh the receipt you have to do it manually, which results in user interaction. That is probably why Apple responded to me that it is not possible to sell both collections and their individual items as IAPs.

Comment: This isn't so different from "If I buy A on iPhone why isn't it immediately on my iPad"? While you can't rely on Apple to tell you you've already purchased this item, you can trigger a refresh when the user tries to buy A, at which time you'd see they'd already bought ABC; if they hadn't you can continue with the purchase.